# javaw.exe crashes on creating JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm using eclipse on a windows 7 x64 to create a new Java Application.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class Testen {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Testen window = new Testen();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Testen() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("1");
        frame = new JFrame();
        System.out.println("2");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

My program is crashing on the line:

```
 frame = new JFrame();
```

It is not giving any error, it's just waiting a second or two, and then my application stops running.

In the event viewer I get this errors:

```
Faulting application name: javaw.exe, version: 7.0.10.8, time stamp: 0x4e8975e3
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
Faulting process id: 0x1334
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccb4bf9aaa4d8d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: d9936f72-20b2-11e1-916b-904ce5de36f8
```

```
Faulting application name: javaw.exe, version: 7.0.10.8, time stamp: 0x4e8975e3
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000000000
Faulting process id: 0x1334
Faulting application start time: 0x01ccb4bf9aaa4d8d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: dd4f2583-20b2-11e1-916b-904ce5de36f8
```

```
Fault bucket 2569546253, type 5
Event Name: BEX64
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: javaw.exe
P2: 7.0.10.8
P3: 4e8975e3
P4: StackHash_1dc2
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 00000000
P7: 0000000000000000
P8: c0000005
P9: 0000000000000008
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\jdc\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD617.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\jdc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_javaw.exe_c49c9b915a42e5982f3a993e0cb1afabe4de2bb_168ced10

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: d9936f72-20b2-11e1-916b-904ce5de36f8
```

```
Fault bucket 50876441, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: javaw.exe
P2: 7.0.10.8
P3: 4e8975e3
P4: StackHash_b541
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 00000000
P7: c000041d
P8: 0000000000000000
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\jdc\AppData\Local\Temp\WEREE86.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\jdc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_javaw.exe_936cbeffcc52c8ea801f518b59b6ee71645a626_1c350580

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: dd4f2583-20b2-11e1-916b-904ce5de36f8
Report Status: 0
```

Does anybody has any idea on how to solve this? Or where should I start looking for a solution?

EDIT:

This works perfectly fine under linux. (Biggest difference is the java version)

Comment: copy paste your codes into Netbeans 7.1 rc1, works as expected ...

Comment: It also works on my virtual WinXP test machine. I would like to get it to work on my development machine.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on 1 of 10 (supposedly) identically configured windows 7 64 bit machines.  Happens on a program that does absolutely nothing except instantiate a JFrame.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I never found out why. It was on an 'old' machine with lots of java updates.. .  I uninstalled them all. and did a clean java install.  That helped for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other java programs also had troubles on my machine..

A complete uninstall and reïnstall of all the java components fixed it.     I guess I'll never know the real reason.. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Nothing else except a missing `import`

`import javax.swing.JFrame;`

Comment: Hey, It seems that I forgot to copy my very first line, wich was import javax.swing.JFrame    So this doesn't help me.    When the import is not there, the program does not start..  my program starts but ends unexpectedly, even without hitting any catch.  System.out.println("1"); is shown,  System.out.println("2"); is never shown.

Comment: @JDC this program worked fine for me , in netbeans, printed both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Testen {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Testen window = new Testen();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Testen() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("1");
        frame = new JFrame();
        System.out.println("2");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```